# Seek date based on array contents

Tags: php

I need to display months based on current month. So if it is July, I want to return only the next 4 months eg, "august", "september", "october" and "november".

How can I do this?

```
$mnth = date('F');
$mnth_arr = array("january","febuary","march","april","may","june","july","august","september","october","november","december");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite simple with the [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) classes:-

```
$now = new \DateTime();
$interval = new \DateInterval('P1M');
$period = new \DatePeriod($now->add($interval), $interval, 4);

foreach($period as $date){
    echo $date->format('F') . "<br/>";
}
```

Output:-

> August
>   September
>   October
>   November
>   December

Answer (score 0):

```
$key = array_search($mnth, $mnth_arr);
for($key; $key<$key+4; $key++)
{
  echo $mnth_arr[$key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use strtotime with relative offsets to accomplish this.

```
 // get the next four months.

 $ref = strtotime("+1 month");
 for($x =0; $x<4; $x++){
       echo  date("F", $ref)."\n";
       $ref = strtotime("+1 month", $ref);
 }
```